# Does Windows Azure Blob Storage support serving compressed files similar to Amazon S3?

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

For example, at Amazon S3, there is a convention, if you have both 'bundle.js' and 'bundle.js.gz' uploaded to the server, and a client requests for 'bundle.js' file with 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' header, Amazon S3 will serve the compressed version of this file ('bundle.js.gz' instead of 'bundle.js').

Does Windows Azure Storage support this? If not, what are workarounds?

Answer (score 9):

Azure Storage allows you to define `Content-Encoding` property on a blob. For compressed content, you could set this property to be `GZIP` and when this content is served by a browser, it automatically decompresses the content and shows the uncompressed content.

This is a bit different than Amazon S3 though where you actually have to upload 2 files. Here you will only upload one file (bundle.js in your example) which is compressed and has content-encoding set as `GZIP`.

Comment: Will it serve uncompressed content (in case browser doesn't support gzip decoding)?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the content served will always be compressed. It is the responsibility of the consumer (browser in this case) to decompress it if it finds `GZIP` in content-encoding response header. So if the browser does not support GZIP decoding, it will show uncompressed content. For example, I just tried to download a compressed file via Fiddler and it showed me compressed data however if I download the same file via Firefox browser it shows me correct file data.

Comment: Are you sure that if you upload both `bundle.js` (uncompressed) and `bundle.js.gz` (compressed) Azure won't serve you a compressed version if you request `bundle.js` with Accept-Encoding: gzip header? This seems like a standard feature. Would be sad if Azure doesn't support it yet.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, I only uploaded bundle.js which was compressed before uploading. Let me try some more.

Comment: So I tried the following - I uploaded bundle.js (uncompressed) and bundle.js.gz (compressed) and tried to read bundle.js through .Net code and provided `Accept-Encoding: gzip` request header. I got back uncompressed content. Then I tried to fetch bundle.js.gz and provided same request header. I got back compressed content. I don't think Azure supports dynamic decompression.

Answer (score 8):

As of 12th August 2015 Azure CDN (mounted on blob storage) now supports automatic GZip compression.

> Compression method - Supported compression methods are
>   gzip/deflate/bzip2, a supported method must be set in the
>   Accept-Encoding Request Header.

[Improve performance by compressing files](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-improve-performance/)