# Does Power Query support Accept-Encoding: gzip in Web.Contents()?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Here's a file with no compression in blob storage:
https://gregsouthcentralstorage.blob.core.windows.net/publiccontainer/TestFile.txt

And here's the same file but gzip compressed and with the Content-Encoding blob property set to GZIP (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263129/does-windows-azure-blob-storage-support-serving-compressed-files-similar-to-amaz)):
https://gregsouthcentralstorage.blob.core.windows.net/publiccontainer/TestFileGzip.txt

The second file is half the size but when I look at them in a web browser both look identical because the web browser can interpret the headers in the response that say "Content-Encoding: gzip"

Now try to consume that first file in Power Query which works as expected:

```
let
    Source = Web.Contents("https://gregsouthcentralstorage.blob.core.windows.net/publiccontainer/TestFile.txt"),
    #"Imported Text" = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(Source,null,null,1252)})
in
    #"Imported Text"
```

However I can't seem to consume the second file in Power Query. This returns gibberish because it never decompresses the gzip content:

```
let
    Source = Web.Contents("https://gregsouthcentralstorage.blob.core.windows.net/publiccontainer/TestFileGzip.txt", [Headers=[#"Accept-Encoding"="gzip"]]),
    #"Imported Text" = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(Source,null,null,1252)})
in
    #"Imported Text"
```

Is there any way to consume gzipped web content in Power Query?

**Update**: Per Carl Walsh's answer below, I had capitalized Content-Encoding: GZIP on the properties of my blob. I've uploaded a new blob with Content-Encoding: gzip (lowercase) and it works:

```
let
    Source = Web.Contents("https://gregsouthcentralstorage.blob.core.windows.net/publiccontainer/TestFileGzipLowercase.txt"),
    #"Imported Text" = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(Source,null,null,1252)})
in
    #"Imported Text"
```

Comment: BTW, Power Query by default handles gzip and deflate encodings. I'd avoid changing the accept encoding header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lukasz points out, everything justs work in the current version of Power BI Desktop, 2.28. The public download of Power Query version, 2.27, came out, but in the next monthly release it will start working.

The issue is that the Azure Blob HTTP response contains the Content-Encoding value "GZIP" but `Web.Contents` used to only automatically decompress when the encoding was lowercase "gzip". (Until we fixed it!)

---

On older version of Power Query, the workaround is to manually decompress GZip with `Binary.Decompress`:

```
let
    Source = Binary.Decompress(Web.Contents("https://gregsouthcentralstorage.blob.core.windows.net/publiccontainer/TestFileGzip.txt", [Headers=[#"Accept-Encoding"="gzip"]]), Compression.GZip),
    #"Imported Text" = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(Source,null,null,1252)})
in
    #"Imported Text"
```

*But this will break once you upgrade to version 2.28.* (Hopefully making the breaking change was the right choice.)

Comment: Oh that's even better news. I'm in control of the Content-Encoding property so I changed it to lowercase and it works in Excel 2013 now even without specifying Accept-Encoding. Brilliant. Thanks Carl.

Answer (score 1):

Greg, I tried this on the latest public build of Power BI desktop and it worked like a charm.

Update based on Greg's comment:
In Excel 2013, set the Content-Encoding property to lowercase and it works without specifying Accept-Encoding. (Thanks Carl & Greg!)

The query that works (which is exactly what you wrote I think :)

```
let
    Source = Web.Contents("https://gregsouthcentralstorage.blob.core.windows.net/publiccontainer/TestFileGzip.txt", [Headers=[#"Accept-Encoding"="gzip"]]),
    #"Imported Text" = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(Source,null,null,1252)})
in
    #"Imported Text"
```

Comment: Ah. I was using the latest build for Excel 2013. Thanks.